# Show element on click, Hide when click on a different div

Tags: javascript

The title says it all.
I got no problems showing an element when clicked.

But I wanted to hide it whenever I click somewhere else.
A good Example of it is the 'StackExchange' label in the header of this site.
When I click on it, it will show additional options.
But When I click elsewhere, It will hide.

Comment: "click elswhere" is basically a listener on `window`.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I can use the toggle effect but I wanted it to hide when the user click outside the div. Toggle only works when you click the same element that triggered the div to show. I don't know how to call it so I can't have a good search.

Comment: provide ur code what u have done so far

Comment: ow. I'm sorry. It took me while because jsfiddle won't allow me to use javascript and I gotta find a way to make it work. here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/AN2JE/ What I wanted is for the orange div to hide when I click anywhere in the window aside from the div itself. I tried using the window.onclick = function() {document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'none';} like the other commenter said but It hides the div even if it is clicked in the div itself. It should only hide when clicked outside the orange div

Answer (score 0):

`window.onclick = function() { alert('it was so simple, wasn\'t it?'); };`

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event when you clicking something,and judge whether it belongs to html:

```
function addListener(element, e, fn) {  //add event function,browser compatible
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(e, fn, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent("on" + e, fn);
    }
}
addListener(document, "click",
function(evt) {
    var evt = window.event ? window.event: evt,
    target = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
    if (target.id == "showDiv") {  //the div you want to show 
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
        return;
    } 
    else {
        //judge target belongs to html or not,You may change condition here
        while (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "div" && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "html") {  
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "html") {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
        }

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Michal Leszczyk  is right, use window handler to hide div

also use event.stopPropagation() when you show div on click. To prevent hiding it at the same time